# How to get pixel positions when cropping a raster with rasterio? (Faster)

Tags: raster, rasterio, masking

I am trying to crop a raster but instead of just getting the values of the cropped raster I am trying to get the positions of that values on the matrix.
I already did this with this code:

```
import geopandas
import rasterio
import rasterio.mask
import numpy as np

shp = gpd.read_file('myshapefile.shp')
with rasterio.open('mytif.tif') as src:
    mask_shp = [feature['geometry'] for feature in json.loads(shp.to_json())['features']]
    for index in range(len(mask_shp)):
        out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, [mask_shp[index]], crop=False, nodata=np.nan)
        z,x,y = np.where(~np.isnan(out_image))
        #Some calculations using the positions of pixels inside the geometry
```

The problem with the code above is that it is very slow, the part which makes it slow is setting crop=False.

When I set crop=False the output dimension of cropped raster is the same as the original raster so I can calculate the positions of pixels inside polygon with np.where(~np.isnan(out_image))

But the difference of time when setting crop=False instead of crop=True is too high, I wonder if there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this faster. I created a temporal raster of the same size than the original but with different values, the value of each pixel is the position of that pixel. For example for a 10x10 raster:

```
0  1  2  ... 7  8  9
10 11 12 ... 17 18 19
         ...
80 81 82 ... 87 88 89
90 91 92 ... 97 98 99
```

Now If I crop this temporal raster even with the parameter crop=True I can get the pixel positions of the raster much faster